# ObservableCollection and List presentation in WPF

Tags: wpf, list, data-binding, observablecollection

My solution consists of two projects. First project connects to the external server and updates own structure with the data.

In this project I have two following classes:

```
class Quote
{... class fields}

class Quotes:IEnumerable<Quote>
{ List<Quote> list = new List<Quote>(); }

class Main
{
Quotes quotelist = new Quotes;
}
```

Second project is simply UI that is designed to present data from first project on screen using WPF.

For this purpose I have created an `ObservableCollection`:

```
ObservableCollection<Quote> quotes =  new ObservableCollection<Quote>(quotelist);
```

Then, I bind quotes in XAML to a grid.

It does not work meaning that changes to the list is not updated. I suppose that I may try to replace `List` with `ObservableCollection` in the first project but I would prefer not to do it, if possible.

What would be the best practise. In all examples I saw, the list (`ObservableCollection`) is created on `ViewModel` level. In my case, the list is created and updated on lower level. 
How to make quotes (ObservableCollection) aware of changes to quotelist (List)? I hope my description makes sense.

Comment: 1. When you pass the list to ObservableCollection constructor, it just copies items from the collection to ObservableCollection. Any changes to original list are not reftected in ObservableCollection. 2. ObservableCollection is defined in System.ObjectModel.dll and is not specfic to WPF or any other framework. You can use it in your poco classes, business logic or data access components.

Comment: Maybe you dont need to notify ui when business data changes, because they changes only when user performs some action, e.g invokes a command. Then you can refresh your ui in the command handler after you do changes in business components

Comment: That is not correct. Most changes are performed as a result of communication with external server. User input is minimal if any.

Comment: Ok, but who triggers the communication? I mean something like this: `await quotesRepository.LoadData(); OnPropertyChanged("Quotes");

Comment: I decided to use ObservableCollection in project one in place of List. It works but there is an exception raised occasionally. I hope I solved it using so called dispatcher explained on C# forum. I do not understand its idea but it seems to work so far. Answering your question: communication goes both ways. My program sets up async communication port and listens to it. My program can also trigger communication through sync communication port if needed to send anything to the server.

Comment: well, Dispatcher is specific to UI and to WPF and you should not use it in business layer. The cross thread collection synchronization is different problem, but fortunatelly, in WPF 4.5 you can databind to collections that are modified in background thread thanks to BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization method: https://anthymecaillard.wordpress.com/2012/03/24/wpf-4-5-access-to-a-collection-outside-of-the-ui-thread/

Comment: You are most probably right that cross thread synchronization is the problem. Interesting idea. Thank you for your suggestion. I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Then you must somehow allow the first project to notify the second project, that something in the list has changed and the ObservableCollection needs to be updated/refreshed.
I would suggest one of three ways:

- Create an event in the first project and let the second project subscribe to that event with an event handler which updates the observable collection
- Make a delegate property in the first project, and attach to it an method/lambda in the second project which will update the observable collection
- Let your `Quotes` class implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface and bind to it directly

Comment: I am not sure if just letting second project know of changes to the List in project one will be enough. Project two will have to know all details to reflect changes on the screen. How project two will know which item to refresh and what is the updated data on the screen? Saying so, I wonder how ObservableCollection is built. Does it keep link (address) to the original list items (from project one) or holds a copy of them. Other words, will ObservableCollection items change so I only need to reftersh UI?

Comment: ObservableCollection is an Collection which implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface which basically says that it has the `CollectionChanged` event. WPF subscribes to this event, so it knows when the list has changed. The observable collection has no knowledge of the source collection. So yes, there is no other way than to manually let project two know, what exactly has changed, so that it can be reflrected in the UI - no magic here. Obviously you can use ObservableCollection in project one - but this is a code smell for me, as you will introduce UI logic to a BL project.

Comment: ObservableCollection is not specific to UI and notifying outside word about changes from business components is not business logic. Why do you think your own event is not ui logic and CollectionChanged is?